# RxJS test equality of two streams regardless of order

Tags: rxjs

RxJS provides the sequenceEqual operator to compare two streams *in order*. How would one go about testing equality of two streams regardless of order?

Pseudocode:

```
//how do we implement sequenceEqualUnordered?
from([1,2,3]).pipe(sequenceEqualUnordered(from([3,2,1]))).subscribe((eq) => 
  console.log("Eq should be true because both observables contain the same values")
)
```

In my particular use case I need to wait until a certain set of values has been emitted or error but I don't care what order they're emitted in. I just care that each value of interest is emitted once.

Comment: order those two before comparing?

Comment: My example above is pseudocode. In real cases I don't know the ordering of the values that will come from the first observable or necessarily the ordering of values in the second observable. All I care about is that the values are equal upon completion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```js
import { Observable, OperatorFunction, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export function sequenceEqualUnordered<T>(compareTo: Observable<T>, comparator?: (a: T, b: T) => number): OperatorFunction<T, boolean> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => new Observable<boolean>(observer => {
    const sourceValues: T[] = [];
    const destinationValues: T[] = [];
    let sourceCompleted = false;
    let destinationCompleted = false;

    function onComplete() {
      if (sourceCompleted && destinationCompleted) {
        if (sourceValues.length !== destinationValues.length) {
          emit(false);
          return;
        }

        sourceValues.sort(comparator);
        destinationValues.sort(comparator);

        emit(JSON.stringify(sourceValues) === JSON.stringify(destinationValues));
      }
    }

    function emit(value: boolean) {
      observer.next(value);
      observer.complete();
    }

    const subscriptions = new Subscription();

    subscriptions.add(source.subscribe({
      next: next => sourceValues.push(next),
      error: error => observer.error(error),
      complete: () => {
        sourceCompleted = true;
        onComplete();
      }
    }));
    subscriptions.add(compareTo.subscribe({
      next: next => destinationValues.push(next),
      error: error => observer.error(error),
      complete: () => {
        destinationCompleted = true;
        onComplete();
      }
    }));

    return () => subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

As many of RxJS operators have some input parameters and as all of them return functions, `sequenceEqualUnordered` also has some input parameter (mostly the same as Rx's `sequenceEqual` operator) and it returns a function. And this returned function has the `Observable<T>` as the `source` type, and has `Observable<boolean>` as the return type.

Creating a new Observable that will emit `boolean` values is exactly what you need. You'd basically want to collect all the values from both `source` and `compareTo` Observables (and store them to `sourceValues` and `destinationValues` arrays). To do this, you need to subscribe to both `source` and `compareTo` Observables. But, to be able to handle subscriptions, a `subscriptions` object has to be created. When creating a new subscriptions to `source` and `compareTo`, just `add` those subscriptions to `subscriptions` object.

When subscribing to any of them, collect emitted values to appropriate `sourceValues` or `destinationValues` arrays in `next` handlers. Should any errors happen, propagate them to the `observer` in `error` handlers. And in `complete` handlers, set the appropriate `sourceCompleted` or `destinationCompleted` flags to indicate which Observable has completed.

Then, in `onComplete` check if both of them have completed, and if they all are, compare the emitted values and emit appropriate boolean value. If `sourceValues` and `destinationValues` arrays don't have the same lengths, they can't equal the same, so emit `false`. After that, basically sort the arrays and then [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23555773/1253279) the two.

When emitting, emit both the value and `complete` notification.

Also, the return value of function passed to the `new Observable<boolean>` should be the `unsubscribe` function. Basically, when someone unsubscribes from `new Observable<boolean>`, it should also unsubscribe from both `source` and `compareTo` Observables and this is done by calling `() => subscriptions.unsubscribe()`. `subscriptions.unsubscribe()` will unsubscribe from all subscriptions that are `add`ed to it.

TBH, I haven't wrote any tests for this operator, so I'm not entirely sure that I have covered all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea. Use `toArray` on both then `zip` them together finally sort and compare results?